# How to convert the content of a .dat file to a human readable form using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, binaryfiles

There is a file called "settings.dat" which I want to read and edit. On opening this file through Notepad, I get an unreadable encoding.

I'm thinking this is probably a binary file. And the encoding is probably UTF-16, as far as I can tell. This is how I tried to convert it:

```py
with open('settings.dat', 'rb') as binary_file:
    raw_data = binary_file.read()
    str_data = raw_data.decode('utf-16', 'ignore')
    print(str_data)
```

The Output is again an unreadable form, with characters that look Chinese. Isn't this supposed to be a simple bytes-to-string conversion problem? Here is the output:

`䕗䙃h 3 Ԁ ː    ᙫ         ␐☐ᜐ┐Ⱀ⨐ᴐሐ⼐【ㄐ㈐䠐倐䬐䴐ᄐἐḐ‐점퀐쬐촐`

Comment: The data file might be read as a unicode file. Many unicode characters are chinese.

Comment: It’s likely that the file is binary, as in: There is no text there. So if this comes from some application, your only chance is to figure out what the application writes there and how. There is nothing *generic* that you could do here.

Comment: @poke Yes it does come from an application. A game, to be precise. And the game is developed by Konami, which is Japanese. 
But shouldn't the conversion still be possible? Most settings.txt files coming from games are modifiable.

Comment: You also have korean text. Many of 'japanese kanji' you provided are not used in japanese ; they are non-Joyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.dat files are *generic* files, and can *either* be binary or text. These files are usually accessed and used only for application support, and each application treats .dat files differently. Hence, .dat files follow no specific protocols which affect all .dat files, unlike .gif or .docx files.

If you want to understand how .dat files work and convert to human-readable form, you need to know how the application handles these files beforehand.

For the Chinese characters, you tried to decode the binary .dat file by the UTF-16 format. That does not change the file content; you are just grouping sequences of bytes of repeating sequences of `bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb = xxxx` where the `b` are the bytes and the `x` are the hexadecimal digits.

Many Unicode characters are Chinese [technically they are called ideographs or ideographic] whereas others are unused, aka reserved.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So you're saying the conversion isn't possible unless I know the interaction between .dat files and the application? And if so, can you provide links to some useful learning resources for the same? Just to get an idea.

Comment: You should learn more about binary files online, search up examples of binary codes, and code a simple application which processes these binary files.

Unfortunately, there isn't much you can do to handle binary files for this game unless you investigate extremely closely in the code. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file. A few .dat files contain text segments which might be delimited by certain binary patterns.

Comment: I get what you're saying. I'm just a beginner, and eager to learn more. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Got it! Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Not a python answer, but the [`strings`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) command line tool is often invaluable in reverse engineering data formats, letting you easily skim through a binary in search for finding familiar plaintext patterns. Obviously if some kind of encryption/compression is used (such as commonly used gzip) it won't help and needs some preprocessing first.

Calling it is as simple as that:

```
user@host:~/ $ strings mydir/settings.dat
```

Comment: Is there a Windows equivalent?

Comment: I don't know of a Windows equivalent, but you can use Linux commands under Windows 10 easily via [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) - that's what I use at work, where  Windows is forced on our workstations via company policy.

Comment: Looks interesting! Will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @AbrezJ, you can also use strings.exe from Sysinternals package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings

Comment: Any Windows alternative?

Answer (score -1):

If it's a binary file, then why do you want to view it? Unless you're aware beforehand that settings.dat contains human-readable characters, it does not make sense to attempt to "find" an encoding so that the output is human-readable characters, because you won't be successful.

On the other hand, if you *do* know that settings.dat contains human-readable characters, then maybe utf-16 is the wrong encoding.